# JQuery Terminal - How to prevent a command line being displayed in the terminal history

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-terminal

Does anyone know how to prevent a command from going into history in JQuery Terminal?
That is, when a command is typed it triggers my :

```
var term = $('body').terminal(
  function(command) {
    //stuff here for dealing with the contents of 'command'.
  }
```

Main hander function.
When this function returns, terminal will then insert a line on the page and display a new prompt line underneath.

What I want to do (optionally) is say 'this command I've intercepted and worked on doesn't need to go into history'.

Alternatively how can I delete the last command from history?

Is that possible?

Edit: By way of avoiding XY problems: The task I'm trying to achieve is to create a terminal, and then on behalf of the user, enter commands. Ideally entry of the commands would be animated (a delay between letters). It's nearly working but not quite.

Comment: By history, do you mean the output on the terminal? Because there is another history called History when you press the up arrow it will show you the commands that you previously type.

Comment: To disable adding a command into output you can use `echoCommand` option. To disable command line history you can use `history` or `historyFilter` first is a boolean value second is a function that returns boolean.

Comment: @jcubic yes.. the output on the terminal, not the 'up and down arrow' history (like bash). Sorry

Comment: Then you need to use `echoCommand: false` option and if you want to have the command appear conditionally you will need to echo it yourself.

Comment: @jcubic Sorry to bother you.. Is there a 'function' for this, ie something like term.setEcho(false) etc.?
I can't find it in the docs.

Comment: There is a method `option()` to change the settings, but I think that it's missing in API Reference. It's in the TypeScript definition file. Here is an example https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/dyeVeGb

Comment: @jcubic Great work BTW